# UIInputViewController keyboard not displaying in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

I created custom keyboard. but some times My keyboard is not displayed in my iOS8 iPhone5S

Please check the below code. I did anything wrong.

My code:

```
   // Perform custom UI setup here
self.nextKeyboardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

[self.nextKeyboardButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Next Keyboard", @"Title for 'Next Keyboard' button") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.nextKeyboardButton sizeToFit];
self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.nextKeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:self.nextKeyboardButton];

NSLayoutConstraint *nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nextKeyboardButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nextKeyboardButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];



UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 160.0);
[self.view  addSubview:button];


[self.view addConstraints:@[nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint]];
```

Comment: Try press Cmd+K to toggle keyboard (on simulator)

Answer (score 2):

Have you followed this steps? because its working perfect for me. more you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)

```
Use the toolbar to ensure that the active scheme specifies the containing app and an iOS Simulator device.

Choose Product > Run, or click the Play button at the upper left of the Xcode project window.
After the containing app and keyboard build and get installed in the simulator, you see the empty containing app running.

In iOS Simulator, choose Hardware > Home to view Springboard.
Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards.
Tap Add New Keyboard.

In the Purchased Keyboards group, tap the name of your new keyboard. A modal view appears with a switch to enable your keyboard.

Tap the switch to enable your keyboard. A warning alert appears.
In the warning alert, tap Add Keyboard to finish enabling your new keyboard. Then tap Done.
Choose Hardware > Home to view Springboard.

In Springboard, pull down to reveal the Spotlight search field.

In the system keyboard, now onscreen, tap and hold the globe key to show the list of enabled keyboards. Then tap on the custom keyboard you just installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The same here ! I concluded that it is a bug from iOS8 beta version .You can display the keyboard again by quiting the app in which the keyboard display , and restart the app then keyboard shows up normally.